# Help explaining formula to calc students

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

This is a stupid question but what is the proper name of this formula? Been trying to look for a proper definition for this but can't find it online. It's been a long time since I had to use these that my brain is drawing a blank.

$$||a||=\sqrt{\left(\frac{{\rm d}^{2}y}{{\rm d}t^{2}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{{\rm d}^{2}x}{{\rm d}t^{2}}\right)^{2}}$$

Edit: just found it used in this question:
[Acceleration of a particle described by parametric equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241312/acceleration-of-a-particle-described-by-parametric-equations)

So it's the magnitude of the vector's speed?

Comment: Note: the derivatives in your formula should be first derivatives, which you then square, not the second derivatives you've written.

Comment: I’m pretty sure there’s a typo in your post. Did you mean square of the first derivative.

Comment: No I meant second derivative

Comment: Just edited it with a link to page where it's being used

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbf{c}(t) = (x(t),y(t))$, then $\frac{ds}{dt}$ is the derivative of arc length with respect to $t$.  If you think of $\mathbf{c}(t)$ as the position of a particle, $\mathbf{c}'(t)=(x'(t),y'(t))$ is its velocity and $||\mathbf{c}'(t)|| = \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}$ is its *speed*.